# Efficient way of evaluating an array of strings then add to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, optimization, array, evaluation

I am looking for an efficient way of evaluating an array of strings against a series of rules and then adding them to another array.

For example I have an array of strings:

1. something
2. a
3. 1234
4. #gohere

I want to iterate through all the items in the array and evaluate them based on a series of rules. For example:

- Strings greater that 1 in length
- Strings that don't start with the # character

I was thinking of either:

1. Nested loop of if statements evaluating the string for each rule and if they all pass then add to another array
2. Evaluating the string against rule 1 then adding to the array then performing another evaluation - I have discounted this since it requires lots of array read/write operations to evaluate the complete ruleset.

Please note that I have kept the number of rules to two for brevity however I could be needing up to 10 rules. Additionally, I do not control the original array since the function I am calling returns an array of strings.

I know I may have answered my own question with the nested loop however I wondered if anyone had any ideas for optimizing this type of situation.

Also, I know I asked this question in the reference of Ruby but any pseudo-code would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Array#select and pass it a block that &&s together all the tests.  If the tests get unwieldy you can abstract them into a method or series of methods.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the select method. I haven't seen or used this to date and looks like it could be useful.

Comment: There's a reject method as well. They are analogous to the filter/remove functions in other languages and great for operating on collections.

Answer (score 1):

Make each rule a lambda, such as this one that returns true if the string length is greater than 1:

```
->(s) {s.length > 1}
```

Make an array of all of the rules that a string must pass for it to match.  Unless the list of rules changes, make it a constant:

```
RULES = [
  ->(s) {s.length > 1},
  ->(s) {s =~ /^#/},
]
```

If any of the rules are complicated, give them their own constant, the name of the constant serving as a comment.  As with @sebastiangeiger's answer, order the rules by probability of failure.  You want to fail as early as possible, if speed is essential.

To see if a string matches, use the "any?" predicate:

```
RULES.all? do |rule|
  rule.call(s)
end
```

Enumerable#all? short-curcuits, so the first rule that returns *false* will prevent the remaining rules from being evaluated for that string.

Now, to find all strings which match all rules:

```
matching_strings = strings.select do |string|
  RULES.all? do |rule|
    rule.call(string)
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this, Wayne. +1

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that a `for loop` or a `select` are equal in terms of efficiency. You can always implement both options and [benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) them.

What you can optimise is the body of the iteration. If you have multiple rules and you join those together using `and` ruby will do [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and return after it found the first `false` value. Hence the order of those rules is important.

Now you need to find out:

1. Which rule is most likely to return `false`
2. Which rule will evaluate quickest

Order the rules from fastest to slowest and/or most likely to fail to least likely to fail. Without a specific problem however I can't give you a more specific answer. And as with everything in optimisation, always measure first.

---

Totally contrived example

```
require 'benchmark'
def slow_and_false
  sleep 0.1
  false
end

def fast_and_false
  sleep 0.005
  false
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("slow first") do
    100.times do
      slow_and_false and fast_and_false
    end
  end
  x.report("fast first") do
    100.times do
      fast_and_false and slow_and_false
    end
  end
end
```

The result of this:

```
            user     system      total        real
slow first  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 ( 10.086344)
fast first  0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  0.560307)
```

Comment: Killed two birds with one stone! The application I am developing requires some serious optimisation in the other components which I haven't even thought about and this is going to give me an opportunity to develop and test.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the answer below to a [similar question at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172175/839601):

```
module Checks
  def _invalid_permission() nil end
  def _check_another_error() "oops!" end
  def _and_another_one() nil end
end

class Doit
  @@checks = Checks.instance_methods(false)
  include Checks

  def doit
    @@checks.each { |m| rv = send(m); return rv if rv }

    "test"
  end
end

p Doit.new.doit # => "oops!"
```

If you change

```
def _check_another_error() "oops!" end
```

to

```
def _check_another_error() nil end
```

then

```
p Doit.new.doit # => "test"
```

Obviously, the check methods can be called with arguments.

This approach allows you to add, remove or rename a check method without having to remember to change references to it elsewhere.